# Export to csv showing undefined index UiComponentFactory.php

Tags: magento2.3, magento2.3.0

I have used the below code in view :

```
<exportButton name="export_button">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">pos_outlet_listing.pos_outlet_listing.pos_outlet_columns.ids</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
</exportButton>
```

Got Error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: attributes in /home/yaboow/public_html/demo/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php on line 176
```

version 2.3

Is there anything i have missed!!?

Comment: Have you add column of primary key in your listing grid?

Comment: '<argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>' added like this under data source tag

Comment: Can you please your listing file code.So i can help you

Comment: https://github.com/azlamptb/Magento You can see the file here

Comment: <!-- <selectionsColumn name="ids">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="resizeDefaultWidth" xsi:type="string">55</item>
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </selectionsColumn> --> just uncomment this

your code will work as expected

Comment: Thank you soo much !!  It is working fine now

Comment: Happy Coding!!!!!!

Comment: @RutveeSojitra, I don't have such node in my xml file, but facing same issue, can u pls help me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
       <!-- <selectionsColumn name="ids"> <argument name="data" xsi:type="array"> <item name="config" xsi:type="array"> <item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item> <item name="resizeDefaultWidth" xsi:type="string">55</item> <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">id</item> </item> </argument> </selectionsColumn> -->
```

> You just need to remove comment form above code.
>   Because UiComponentFactory.php take Data of array from  it and pass this data to it's parent

```
     public function __construct(
    ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
    ManagerInterface $componentManager,
    InterpreterInterface $argumentInterpreter,
    ContextFactory $contextFactory,
    array $data = [],
    array $componentChildFactories = [],
    DataInterface $definitionData = null,
    DataInterfaceFactory $configFactory = null
) {
    $this->objectManager = $objectManager;
    $this->componentManager = $componentManager;
    $this->argumentInterpreter = $argumentInterpreter;
    $this->contextFactory = $contextFactory;
    $this->componentChildFactories = $componentChildFactories;
    $this->configFactory = $configFactory ?: $this->objectManager->get(DataInterfaceFactory::class);
```

**parent::__construct($data);**

```
            $this->definitionData = $definitionData ?:
        $this->objectManager->get(DataInterface::class);
}
```

And it's parent class

> **Magento\Framework\DataObject**

data set in **SetData** function

Comment: hi @Rutvee, I am also facing same issue, but i do not see any code like that in my listing.xml, the export is working well only i need to change the csv file to store in media directory

Comment: @jafarpinjar How can you change the CSV file to store in media directory? i'm facing the same issue

Answer (score 5):

Check if yo have selection columns, if not add this

```
    <selectionsColumn name="ids">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="resizeDefaultWidth" xsi:type="string">55</item>
                <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">id</item>
            </item>
       </argument>
    </selectionsColumn>
```