# How to add Upload Button for importing a csv file in the Custom Admin Grid

Tags: magento2

Add import button in my custom admin grid using UI component, in magento 2.

Comment: please refer this link :- https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/283747/export-button-in-custom-grid-magento-2?rq=1

Comment: How to add import button functionality in the custom admin grid